# How can I call other action in the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I call other action in the same controller?
Then I want to pass `@community or @user` and `params[:comment][:body]` to `part_two`

My current code is this.

```
def part_one
    if params[:mode] == "1"
        @community = Community.find(params[:id])
        @body = "This is for Community"
    elsif params[:mode] == "2"
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @body = "This is for User"
    end

    params[:comment][:body] = @body

    -----here I want to call action [part_two]-------
end


def part_two
    transaction that needs @community or @user,  and params[:comment][:body]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
def part_one
    if params[:mode] == "1"
        @community = Community.find(params[:id])
        @body = "This is for Community"
    elsif params[:mode] == "2"
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @body = "This is for User"
    end

    params[:comment][:body] = @body

    # call part_two
    part_two
end
```

This will call part_two method in the same controller.

Comment: Thanks very much. Does it even pass `params[:comment][:body]` to part_two?

Comment: Yes, `params[:comment][:body]` should be availabe in `part_two` as well. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: this really won't work as expected if both part_one and part_two are controller actions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call an action from another action.

From your code example, it sounds like your action should be `part_two`, but that your `part_one` should be a *before filter* for that action.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: Thanks `part_one` will be called by accessing `example.com/:mode/:id` but `part_two` will be called from Form. In my case, how should I do this?

Comment: why cannot call an action from another action?

Comment: @sevenseacat should I probably put `part_two` into application_controller?